# Getting error message in Sitecore item

Tags: sitecore-client

I am getting below error while publishing Sitecore item.

> If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the
>   Web site because it is not in the final workflow step. No other
>   version will be published.

Just wanted to know, why i am getting this?

Comment: This is no error message - this is just a warning that if you publish the version you are viewing will not be published because it is part of a workflow and not in the final step of that workflow..

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error. It's a warning message.

It means that item has a workflow applied and it's not in the final state yet.

Check `Workflow state` field of your item:

[image]

In the `Review` tab of your ribbon you should see something like `Approve` button. Click it to move it to the final step of your workflow.

[image]

Comment: To add a little bit extra, here is the Sitecore documentation on this topic: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/managing_items/workflows/move_an_item_to_the_next_workflow_state